# Simple Angular JS application not showing up on browser

Tags: angularjs, html

I created two pages `index.html` and `app.js`(Basically following the tutorial from [here](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro)) , the contents of each of them are as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="store">
    <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
          <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
          <h2> ${{store.product.price}} </h2>
          <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
          <button ng-show ="store.product.canPurchase"> Add to cart </button>
       </div>



       <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    </body>




</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){)
var app = angular.module('store',[]);
app.controller('StoreController',function() {
    this.product = gem;

});
var gem = {

    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description:'. . .',
    canPurchase: false
}
})();
```

For some reason, it's not actually printing the values on the web browser, here is what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Open you console (CTRL+SHIFT+J, or CMD+SHIFT+I on Mac). Do you have the angular library in the right place (e.g. `angular-1.3.14/angular.min.js` relative to your html file), or do you see a 404 when you open your console?

Comment: The error is `gem is undefined` :) Move that variable declaration above the code that uses it.

Comment: look at the syntax error (function(){) it should be (function(){ }) and code comes inside {}

Comment: ^ that too haha. John, check your console and handle the errors. You should never post until you've handled the errors your console is telling you about.

Comment: No gem is not the error @m59 check i added  plunker :-)

Comment: How about that... It's ugly having the variable there, but I guess it works after all. I would try to avoid answering syntax error questions though. It should just be closed and deleted.

Comment: Thanks everyone.After removing the syntax error, only `$` is getting printed on the Firefox and Chrome and IE browser.The console is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error remove ")"

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store',[]);
app.controller('StoreController',function() {
    this.product = gem;

});
var gem = {

    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description:'. . .',
    canPurchase: false
}
})();
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkAEnae4NCcCcFTJVPif?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
var app= angular.module('GemsStore',[]);

app.controller('StoreController', function() {
var gems = [{
    name: 'Diamond',
    price: 100,
    description: 'Shiny',
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false
},
    {
        name: 'Sapphire',
        price: 200,
        description: 'Shiny',
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: false
    }

];

this.products = gems;
});
```

i had the same problem this works